# Accessing nested dictionary values matching a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator, lookup

What I am trying to do is iterate through this dictionary and grab out only the keys that have "RM" in them (including their value).

I have tried things like:

```
for key, val in release_dict["packages"].items():
        for k, v in val.items():
            print(item for item in v["linked_jiras"] if "RM" in item)
```

without much luck at all.

I'm stuck here

```
{
    "packages": {
        "company-web-package-name": {
            "linked_jiras": {
                "RM-2048": "info we want",
                "RM-2087": "info we want",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
            },
            "branch": "master",
            "project_lead": "person"
        },
        "company-web-package": {
            "linked_jiras": {
                "RM-1880": "info we want",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
            },
            "branch": "master",
            "project_lead": "person"
        },
        "company-web-package--internal": {
            "linked_jiras": {
                "RM-2049": "info we want",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
                "item": "description",
            },
            "branch": "master",
            "project_lead": "person"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to either get a new dictionary of those results or more simply a tuple of those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorder your loops slightly and add to output dictionary to get all infos:

```
d = {}

for key, val in release_dict["packages"].items():
    for item in val["linked_jiras"]:
        if "RM" in item:
            d[item] = val["linked_jiras"][item]

print(d)
# {'RM-2048': 'info we want', 'RM-2087': 'info we want', 'RM-1880': 'info we want', 'RM-2049': 'info we want'}
```

***Note***: Make sure that if you are using dictionaries, all `'RM'` keys are distinct.

Comment: This is wonderful thank you. If i were to change it to "I only want to grab the project_lead names", that would get a little more complicated, correct?

Comment: @NathanPhillips , that should be `val['project_lead']`.

Comment: Appreciate everything :)